# Selecting a different object hides all keyframes in timeline?

Tags: animation, interface, keyframes

There are two objects in my 3D-view:

- A red object
- A white object

Both are overlapping each other.

I have added several keyframes of animation to the red object. 
When I select the white object, all keyframes disappear from timeline.
They reappear if I select the red object again.

Why do keyframes disappear from the timeline?
What am I missing?

Comment: I think this is supposed to happen, the keyframes are hidden to keep the view clean..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a *feature*. You only see keyframes for the selected object in the timeline. If you want to see all your keyframes, I would use the *Dope Sheet*.
[image]

The arrow icon only shows the key frame from the selected object.

The ghost icon shows keyframes form hidden objects.

The life saver :P(*I think that the official name?*) shows broken drivers.

Comment: Just to add: Make sure that the arrow in the top right ("only selected") is turned OFF.

Otherwise this won't work in 2022

Answer (score 7):

[This is how the timeline works](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Timeline):

> The Timeline is not much of an editor, but more of a information and
>   control window.
>
> Here you can have an overview of the animation part of your scene
>       What is the current time frame, either in frames or in seconds, where are the keyframes of the **active object**, the start and end frames
>   of your animation, markers, etc...

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

If you want to see all the keyframes in the scene, use the *[dopesheet](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet)* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>). Click the ghost icon in the header to make keyframes on hidden objects visible:

[image]

Comment: does it again :-) that ghost icon was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue.

the solution in my case was to disable Auto Keying: Editor Type > Timeline > click on the auto key button.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The **ghost icon** was replaced in new Blender versions by this icon (on the right) [image: ghost icon].